# Fake proof that every nonempty subset of $\mathbb R$ has a maximum element

Tags: real-analysis, upper-lower-bounds

Let $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ be nonempty and let sup(A)=$\alpha$. Then we have $$(\forall \epsilon > 0)(\exists x \in A)~x>\alpha-\epsilon$$
Note that $x > \alpha-\epsilon$ for all $\epsilon > 0$ implies $x \geq \alpha$. Additionally, $x \leq \alpha$ since $\alpha$ is an upper bound of A. Thus we get $x = \alpha$, which is not necessarily true.
But I don't know where goes wrong.

Comment: Different $\epsilon$s have different $x$s, so your "proof" that $x \ge \alpha$ isn't valid. It's kind of like going from the statement "everybody has a shoe that they wear" to thinking "that shoe must be filthy if everybody is wearing it".

Comment: See [Order of quantifiers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantifier_(logic)#Order_of_quantifiers_(nesting)) for further explanation.

Comment: Thanks, it got it now

Comment: Sometimes, to emphasise that $x$ may depend on $\varepsilon$, authors write "for every $\varepsilon>0$, there is an $x_{\varepsilon}\in A$ such that $x>\alpha-\varepsilon$". (But note that $x$ may also depend on $A$!)

Comment: Besides the dependence of $x$ on $\epsilon$, there is another problem, that $\alpha$ need not exist or not be a real number ($+\infty$), whichever way you want to express it. In that case, the condition that $+\infty$ satisfies as the supremum of  $A$ doesn't have the inequality $x>\alpha -\epsilon$. Instead the inequality looks like $x>\epsilon$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point is the order of the quantifiers matters. For each $\epsilon$, there is an $x$ which depends on $\epsilon$ such that $x>\alpha-\epsilon$. We’re not saying there is an $x$ such that for every $\epsilon$, $x>\alpha-\epsilon$.

Comment: How should I write the correct expression in formal language?

Answer (score 0):

Your error is here : for all $\varepsilon$, there exists an $x$ that is greater than $\alpha-\varepsilon$.
Here, $x$ depends on $\varepsilon$ because the "there exists" comes after : you find $x$ after having chosen $\varepsilon$. Change $\varepsilon$ and the $x$ you found may not be greater than $\alpha-\varepsilon$.

For instance : let $\alpha=10$ and $\varepsilon=0.1$. Then $x=9.9999$ satisfies $x>\alpha-\varepsilon$.

Now let $\varepsilon=0.01$, then the same $x$ is suitable.

But let $\varepsilon=0.0000000000001$ and now your $x$ is not suitable, you have to find another $x$.

Comment: Thanks, it got it now